# How to render offscreen IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, rendering, cgcontext

I am trying to make a metaball implementation in swift but have ran into this problem on the way. Basically I need to draw some alpha radial gradients offscreen and then check each pixel value to see wether it is above a certain alpha threshold if it is than the pixel becomes black other wise it is white.

The problem is that I cant figure out how to make an offscreen context that I can draw on and perform calculations on and then display it on the screen.

I have searched endlessly but I am very confused with the differences between UIcontexts and CGContext. In my current attempt I use a CGBitmapContext but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated (preferably in swift, but anything goes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw to a bitmap graphics context as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/HandlingImages/Images.html).

Comment: @egdenis If that doesn't help, you should probably post (relevant excerpts of) your current code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can create an image context, draw to it using CG calls, and then get a UIImage:

```
// Create an N*N image
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(N, N);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// EG:
CGColorRef backColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, backColor);
CGContextFillRect(ctx, r1);
.... more drawing code 
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You can get a CGImageRef very easily:

```
CGImageRef cgImage = image.CGImage;
```

Finally, you can get the underlying bytes as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1509/_index.html).